# VF Page Formatting with Repeat values is not working for me

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, table

Need help with getting the formatting correct for this VF page.  The complicated part is I am calling a VF Component withing the page and it is making the repeats not play nice.  The goal is to get the name and address items to create a new row when there is more than one, see pic below.
[image: Report Example]

VF Page "CeaseDesistUSReport":

```
<apex:page standardController="Case__c" recordSetVar="cases" extensions="CeaseDesistUSController">
<style type="text/css">
    table.myTable{
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table.myTable td{
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    table.myTable th{
        border: 2px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    a.linkAsBtn,
    a.linkAsBtn:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 3px 6px;
    }
</style>
  <apex:form >
      <apex:outputPanel >
          <table class="myTable">
              <tr>
                  <th>CASE NUMBER</th>
                  <th>CASE NOTIFICATION DATE</th>
                  <th>PERSON NAME</th>
                  <th>STREET</th>
                  <th>CITY</th>
                  <th>STATE</th>
                  <th>ZIP</th>
              </tr>
              <apex:repeat value="{!selected}" var="c">
              <tr>
                  <td>
                  <a href="https://test.my.salesforce.com/{!c.Id}">{!c.name}</a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                  <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'-'dd'-'yyyy}"><apex:param value="{!c.Notification_Date__c}"/></apex:outputText>
                  </td>
                  <apex:repeat value="{!c.Subject_for_Cases__r}" var="sub">
                  <td>
                        <apex:outputText value="{!sub.Subject_Name__r.Subject_Name__c}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
                  </td>    
                        <c:Person_Residence thePerson="{!sub.Subject_Name__r.Id}"/><br></br>
                  </apex:repeat>
               </tr>
           </apex:repeat> 
           </table>  
      </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

VF Page Controller "CeaseDesistUSController":

```
public class CeaseDesistUSController{

    ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;

    public CeaseDesistUSController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)
    {
        setCon = controller;
    }

    public pageReference doSomething()
    {
        // do something with the selected records
        for ( Case__c cas : (Case__c[])setCon.getSelected() )
        {
                System.debug('Case name = ' + cas.Name);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

VF Component "Person_Residence":

```
<apex:component controller="PersonResidenceController" access="global">
<apex:attribute id="recordID" assignTo="{!recordID}" name="thePerson" type="Id" description="The Person record"/>
        <apex:repeat value="{!sub1}" var="s1">
                <apex:repeat value="{!s1.Home_Addresses__r}" var="addr">
                <td>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!addr.Residence_Street__c}" />         
                </td>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!addr.Residence_City__c}" />          
                </td>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!addr.Residence_State_Province__c}" />          
                </td>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!addr.Residence_Zip_Postal_Code__c}" />
                </td>
                </apex:repeat>
        </apex:repeat>
</apex:component>
```

VF Component Controller "PersonResidenceController":

```
public with sharing class PersonResidenceController {
    Public Id recordID {get;set;}
    public PersonResidenceController () {

    }
    public Subject__c[] sub1 {
        get {                                                                                                          
                Subject__c[] subjectList = 
                    [SELECT Id
                            , Name 
                            , (SELECT Residence_Street__c, Residence_City__c, Residence_State_Province__c, Residence_Zip_Postal_Code__c from Home_Addresses__r)
                    FROM Subject__c
                    WHERE (Id = :recordID)];

            return subjectList ;
        }
        set;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally for this type of scenarios you will create a map which will have  CaseNumber as key and list of Person Names records as values.

When you iterate the map you could find how many person name records are there for each Case Number as key, which will help you to define `<td rowspan="{recordcount of the each case number}">` for Case Number and Case Notification Date

Hope it will help!.

Thanks,
Santanu

Comment: Can you provide some examples?  I am trying to understand how to create the map.  Thanks.

Comment: You can use apex workbook (https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/apex_workbook.pdf) and Visual force in practice (https://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf) for references.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't your "visualforce", it's your hand-coded HTML.  You are probably creating very strange HTML that just keeps adding columns (one column for each subject and then an additional 4 columns for each address).

Instead, add a row for each subject's address.  That solves the basic problem.

If you want it to be fancy like you have (with "merged cells" to use Excel terms), look into `<td>`'s [rowspan](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-rowspan) attribute.  It'll require a bit more thinking, but nothing outlandish (you might need to iterate over a `Map<CaseId, Map<SubjectInfo, List<AddressInfo>>` ([docs on Map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm%23apex_methods_system_map)).

I'd also suggest looking into [`<apex:dataTable>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dataTable.htm?search_text=onclick) instead of making your own.

Comment: Can you provide some examples for the Mapping?  I think that maybe the answer to my problem.  Thx.

Comment: @Nathan I added a link to the Apex Map class documentation in the above answer.  It might help you conceptualize this if you sketched out the HTML you want first.